# Javascript - Regex rule, find XX but not in span tag

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, html

**Text**

```
message = 'Hello, my name ist Peter!';
```

**My Tags**

```
tags = {}; 
tags.tagsOne = {};
tags.tagsOne['t1'] = 'hello|is|there|g';
tags.tagsOne['t2'] = 'bub';
tags.tagsOne['t3'] = 'dog|house';
tags.tagsTwo = {}; 
tags.tagsTwo['t1'] = 'blub|man';
tags.tagsTwo['t2'] = 'word';
tags.tagsTwo['t3'] = 'sorry|high';
```

**Regex**

```
regexT1 = new RegExp('('+tags.tagsOne['t1']+'|'tags.tagsTwo['t1']+')','gi');
regexT2 = new RegExp('('+tags.tagsOne['t2']+'|'tags.tagsTwo['t2']+')','gi');
regexT3 = new RegExp('('+tags.tagsOne['t3']+'|'tags.tagsTwo['t3']+')','gi');
```

**Replace**

```
message = message.replace(regexT1,'<span class="highlightT1">$1</span>');
message = message.replace(regexT2,'<span class="highlightT2">$1</span>');
message = message.replace(regexT3,'<span class="highlightT3">$1</span>');
```

He finds and replaces the `<span class="highlightT1">$1</span>` too.
Is it possible in regex to say, but not this -> `<span class="highlightT1">$1</span>`

**Example**
-> http://jsfiddle.net/tVmTe/3/

**UPDATE:**
**Working example**
-> http://jsfiddle.net/tVmTe/9/

Comment: It's possible, but it will overcomplicate your regexes. It would be much simpler and maintainable to achieve the same result not modifying them. For example, by checking for spcific conditions before fetching strings to those regexes.

Comment: Generally you shouldn't parse html with regex.

Comment: @john, can you give me a little jsfiddle example, i dont understand what you mean. <br />@ Joseph, i only replace words in a text with html code. The second replae is actually unintended. But i have no idea to solve that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the message on space and consider each word individually.

```
var words = message.split(' '),
   var i = 0;
for(i; i < words.length; ++i){
   if(regexT1.test(words[i])){
      words[i] = words[i].replace(regexT1,'<span class="highlightT1">$1</span>');
      continue;
   }
   //...
}
message = words.join(' ');
```